# Kernel compilation after a patch

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel

I have the kernel source of version x.y.z already compiled (and the binary installed); then I
apply the patch to version x.y.z+1, why it recompile all kernel? There is little difference
between two patches.

There is a way to speedup the things?

Comment: Because, obviously, kernel is one big binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the patches apply to the source code (ie the patches aren't binary), and you've already compiled the kernel, then `make` will compile only the changed files provided that the object files generated by the previous compiling are still there. Therefore the compiling process is optimized.

`make` compiles only the modified files, which allows for sgnificant speed-ups on large projects when you modify only some files.

Answer (score 0):

If the patch touches an important header file then you can end up with practically a full recompile just because everything includes that header.

[ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/) can speed things up, especially if you go back and forth between kernel versions.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think to use also ccache.